# Can't get Python IDLE to recognize OGR/GDAL Module

Tags: python, gis, geospatial, gdal, ogr

Folks,

Just getting started using OGR and Python for a variety of geospatial tasks. I'm working outside of OSGEO4w, and have installed GDAL w/ Python Bindings as well as Python v. 2.7.8 on my machine.

That said, I can run python and import gdal from a command-line interface but am unable to import the module when I use the IDLE environment. It returns an error telling me that the module doesn't exist. My install must be sound given that it works in the cmd prompt, so what's the deal?

This is all new to me, I'd appreciate any help or advice ya'll can impart; all previous questions I've read were concerned w/ merely installing (which I've done successfully) and getting Python to recognize the module from the command prompt, which it does.

Cheers,

Mike

Comment: This is most likely because the python you're running from IDLE is a completely different install from the one where you installed GDAL.  Try comparing the result of `import sys; print sys.executable` from IDLE and from the command-line.

Comment: Joe, you're right. My IDLE instance is running from the python install in ArcGIS, while my command-line is using the new install I did outside of ESRI's tools. Any idea on how to get IDLE working w/in the install I'm using outside of ArcGIS? Thanks for your help, I'm a gumbie w/ this stuff.

Comment: So the question is how to use IDLE with OSGeo4W?

Answer (score 1):

Mike,

You can open IDLE with your python installation from the cmd line through:

```
>>>from idlelib import PyShell  
>>>PyShell.main()
```

This should open IDLE from your current python, and you should be able then to import gdal and ogr from there.

Alternatively, you should have a windows batch file here
C:\YOURPYTHONPATH\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat

Running this should achieve the same.

Martin

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating the following batch where **PyInst** references the Python installation folder from which IDLE is launched (i.e. idle.bat) and **QgisInst** references the folder containing "bin\o4w_env.bat":

```
@echo off
set PyInst=C:\Python27
set QgisInst="C:\Program Files\QGIS Brighton"

call %QgisInst%\bin\o4w_env.bat
set PYTHONPATH=%PyInst%\DLLs;%PyInst%\Lib;%PyInst%\Lib\lib-tk
set TCL_LIBRARY=%PyInst%\tcl\tcl8.5
python %PyInst%\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw
```