# Failure to import kml module from fastkml package

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-idle, osgeo

Starting with a command window started by OSGeo4W, I successfully installed the fastkml python package compatible with python 2.7 running on windows 7.

When I run python from the command window, I can import the  kml module from the fastkml package.

However, if I start the IDLE user interface from the same command window and try  importing the  kml module from the fastkml package, I get errors as follows:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
> from fastkml import kml

>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from fastkml import kml
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\fastkml\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import get_distribution, DistributionNotFound
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources.extern.packaging.specifiers')
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\extern\__init__.py", line 42, in load_module
    __import__(extant)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\packaging\specifiers.py", line 275, in <module>
    class Specifier(_IndividualSpecifier):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\packaging\specifiers.py", line 373, in Specifier
    r"^\s*" + _regex_str + r"\s*$", re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
error: nothing to repeat
```

The following is code from the bat file used to start OSgeo4W which in turn starts IDLE

```
@echo off
set OSGEO4W_ROOT=%~dp0
rem Convert double backslashes to single
set OSGEO4W_ROOT=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\\=\%
echo. & echo OSGEO4W home is %OSGEO4W_ROOT% & echo.
set PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%PATH%
rem Add application-specific environment settings
for %%f in ("%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\etc\ini\*.bat") do call "%%f"
CALL C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat
@echo on
@if [%1]==[] (echo run o-help for a list of available commands & cmd.exe /k)    else (cmd /c "%*")
```

Comment: The behavior you report is puzzling.  IDLE should not, and I am tempted to say cannot, affect the creation of the regex or the result of trying to compile it.  Please rerun python from the command window and see whether the initial splash line `Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, ...` is *exactly the same.  After `> from fastkml import kml`, what does `> kml.__file__` return?  If you add `print pattern, flags` to re.compile (before the return), what is printed when running python and IDLE?  What are the command line that you use to start python and IDLE in the console?

Comment: initial splash line is: Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Comment: kml.__file__ returns  C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\fastkml\kml.pyc

Comment: The bat file used to start OSGeo4W and IDLE is now shown in the original posting.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I do not have a  re.compile file. Did you not mean the following file C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\re.py", line 190 ?

Comment: `re.compile` is the `compile` function within the `re` module created from `re.py`.  I meant to insert the line within the body of the function.

Comment: Where is the .bat file located?

Answer (score 1):

AS I suspected, you have two python 2.7s installed.  As near as I can tell from the paths and splash screens:

C:\python27 has 2.7.10, which your batch files uses to run IDLE.

C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27 must have 2.7.4 and this is likely the python that your are running directly, and which does the import correctly.

Running `>>> import sys; sys.executable` in both shells will verify or correct these conclusions.  If they are correct, then a possible fix is to replace `C:\python27` in the batch file with `C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27` so that IDLE is running on the python that worked.  It is, of course, possible that `C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib` does not contain `\idlelib`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes you are correct.  I will return to this later this week  to correct the environment and confirm that all is well.

Comment: The answer given by @strm_1 to the question posted : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836182/cant-get-python-idle-to-recognize-ogr-gdal-module got me sorted. Many thanks.